# Need a way to find matches between two many-to-many-relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following tables:

```
   ------------     ------------
   |     BA   |     |    CA    | 
   ------+-----     ------+-----
   | BId|| AId|     | CId|| AId|
   ------+------     ------+-----
   |  B1 |  2 |     |  C1 |  2 |
   |  B1 |  3 |     |  C2 |  2 |
   |  B2 |  2 |     |  C2 |  3 |
   |  B2 |  4 |     |  C3 |  4 |
   |  B2 |  5 |     |  C3 |  5 |
   ------------     ------------
```

How do I write a query to return only those (DISTINCT) CId's where any set of CA rows having same CId finds an exact match (of AId's) from the similar sets of rows in BA?

In the example above, C2 should be returned, because the rows in CA with [C2,2] and [C2,3] (Can we call it the set of { (n,2), (n,3) }?) finds an exact match in BA: Its first two rows -- [B1,2] and [B1,3] ( Can we call this set { (m,2), (m,3) } ? )

Comment: You're right, @Corion. I need to correct that..

Comment: In BA and CA, AId is the foreign key for Id from A.
BA and CA are many-to-many rels between B and A and C and A respectively. Do I need to be more clear than that?

Comment: Why does `C` have 3 rows of `C1`?

Comment: @Danny: because I'm hasty. Dang! Will correct

Comment: The challenge for me here is that the data is so anonymized it is really hard to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, you want to return every Cn in CA where the A is also in BA?

Comment: Yeah, I tryed to read again and realized I didnt understand at all. Very confused.

Comment: @Corion... Come to think of it, you're right. There was no strict need to show tables A, B, and C to define the problem. Let me edit the question.

Comment: So B2 having three AID's disqualifies it from matching C3, because that only has two of the three AID's in B2?
For each group of CID, the set of AID's in that group must be the same set in a group of some BID.  Is that more like what you're looking for?

Comment: @Corion I'm not sure what you mean by Cn, but let me explain: C1 doesn't qualify because although there is a matching column in BA, ( [B1, 2] ), There is also a [B1, 3]. The set of the second element of each subset of the Cn must find and exact match in the set of Bn's.

Comment: @PeterWard: That's accurate! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements can be calculated using a CTE for `CA` and `BA`. Then you can get at the full rows via:

#### SQL

```
with ca_info as (
      select
           cid
         , count(*) as ccount
        from ca
      group by cid
  ),
ba_info as (
      select
           bid
         , count(*) as bcount
        from ba
      group by bid
  )
select
*
from
    ba
    join ca on (ba.aid = ca.aid)
    join ba_info on ba.bid=ba_info.bid
    join ca_info on ca.cid=ca_info.cid
where ccount = bcount
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/89d391/8)

Results

```
bid     aid     cid     aid     bid     bcount  cid     ccount
B1      2       C2      2       B1      2       C2      2
B1      3       C2      3       B1      2       C2      2
```

If you are just interested in `C2` itself, you can restrict the result set more:

```
with ca_info as (
      select
           cid
         , count(*) as ccount
        from ca
      group by cid
  ),
ba_info as (
      select
           bid
         , count(*) as bcount
        from ba
      group by bid
  )
select
distinct ca.cid
from
    ba
    join ca on (ba.aid = ca.aid)
    join ba_info on ba.bid=ba_info.bid
    join ca_info on ca.cid=ca_info.cid
where ccount = bcount
```

#### Supersets

To also get sub/supersets, the condition enforcing the set-equality can be changed:

```
where ccount <= bcount
```

This returns all sets where Bx as at least as many elements as Cy:

```
bid    aid    cid    aid    bid    bcount    cid    ccount
B1     2      C1     2      B1     2          C1    1
B1     2      C2     2      B1     2          C2    2
B1     3      C2     3      B1     2          C2    2
B2     2      C1     2      B2     3          C1    1
B2     2      C2     2      B2     3          C2    2
B2     4      C3     4      B2     3          C3    2
B2     5      C3     5      B2     3          C3    2
```

Comment: Elegant. What would I need to change if I wanted to include supersets in BA? In that event both C1 and C3 would also be returned.

Comment: thanks! I was about to tell you there wasn't any need to answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `JOIN` and `COUNT`. You first count the CIds (how many times each one of them is repeated). Then, you do the same for BIds. Then, you JOIN BA and link both (AIds) and COUNT. Your target is to match the count of ids and their AIds.

Example :

```
DECLARE 
    @a TABLE(id INT)

INSERT INTO @a VALUES 
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6)

DECLARE 
    @b TABLE(id CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @b VALUES 
('B1'),
('B2'),
('B3')

DECLARE 
    @c TABLE(id CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @c VALUES 
('C1'),
('C2'),
('C3')


DECLARE 
    @ba TABLE(BId CHAR(2), AId INT)

INSERT INTO @ba VALUES 
('B1',2),
('B1', 3),
('B2', 2),
('B2', 4),
('B2', 5)

DECLARE 
    @ca TABLE(CId CHAR(2), AId INT)

INSERT INTO @ca VALUES 
('C1',2),
('C2',2),
('C2',3),
('C3',4),
('C3',5)




SELECT DISTINCT CId 
FROM (
SELECT *
,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CId) cnt
FROM @ca ca
) c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY BId) cnt
    FROM @ba ba
) b ON b.AId = c.AId AND b.cnt = c.cnt 
WHERE 
    b.cnt IS NOT NULL
```

So, in the example C2 has repeated 2 times, and in BA, B1 has repeated also 2 times. This is the first condition, second one is to match both AIds, if they're the same, then you have a group match.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution uses window functions:

```
select ca.cid, ba.bid
from (select ca.*, count(*) over (partition by cid) as cnt
      from ca
     ) ca join
     (select ba.*, count(*) over (partition by bid) as cnt
      from ba
     ) ba
     on ca.aid = ba.aid and ca.cnt = ba.cnt
group by ca.cid, ba.bid, ca.cnt
having ca.cnt = count(*)  -- all match
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67d7bf6fd3094cd70a2f7078219430af) is a db<>fiddle.

The result set is all matching `cid`/`bid` pairs.

The logic here is pretty simple.  For each `cid` and `bid`, the subqueries calculate the count of `aid`s.  This number has to match.

Then the `join` is on `aid` -- this is an inner join, so only matching pairs are produced.  The final `group by` is used to generate the count of matches to see if this tallies up with all the `aid`s.

This particular version assumes that the rows are unique in each table, although the query can easily be adjusted if this is not the case.

Comment: Nicely explained!